# How can I replace one loaded component with another component in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

How can I replace one loaded component with another component in cakephp 3.x?

First I need to download the component: `$this->loadComponent('MainComponentFirs');`

Can I somehow unload the downloaded component, to download after another ?:
`$this->loadComponent('MainComponentSecond');`

It is a prerequisite that both components must not be loaded at the same time. Tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer on a [Github request](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5688), they're no function to unload a component. But you can do it like this:

```
$this->components()->unload('Foo');
unset($this->Foo);
```

You'll just have to load your other component after:

```
$this->components()->unload('MainComponentFirst');
unset($this->MainComponentFirst);
$this->loadComponent('MainComponentSecond');
```

They suggest creating a method like this on your AppController.

Comment: Thanks, SamHecquet ! :)

And thanks: slackebot3, he showed: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php#L329-L337